# Can I have my inheriting class acquire the property values of a parent class instance with less code than this?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I need the separate classes for Xml Serialization. I'd like to know if there is a simpler way for the inheriting *BuildingDetail* class to acquire the property values from the parent *Building* class.

**Parent Class**

```
public class Building
{
    public int BuildingId;
    public string BuildingName;

    protected Building()
    {
    }

    private Building(int buildingId, string buildingName)
    {
        BuildingId = buildingId;
        BuildingName = buildingName;
    }

    public static Building Load(int buildingId)
    {
        var dr = //DataRow from Database

        var building = new Building(
            (int) dr["BuildingId"],
            (string) dr["BuildingName"]);

        return building;
    }
}
```

**Inheriting Class**

```
public class BuildingDetail : Building
{
    public BaseList<Room> RoomList
    {
        get { return Room.LoadList(BuildingId); }
    }

    protected BuildingDetail()
    {
    }

    // Is there a cleaner way to do this?

    private BuildingDetail(int buildingId, string buildingName)
    {
        BuildingId = buildingId;
        BuildingName = buildingName;
    }

    public new static BuildingDetail Load(int buildingId)
    {
        var building = Building.Load(buildingId);

        var buildingDetail = new BuildingDetail(
            building.BuildingId, 
            building.BuildingName
            );

        return buildingDetail;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should really consider changing those public fields to properties instead.

Comment: Yes, they didn't need to be before, but using @ChaseFlorell 's method below I've changed them to properties.

Comment: Sorry, @Farhad-Jabiyev 's method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, change your base class constructor access modifier to `protected`. And then you can call base class constructor with [`base`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) keyword:

```
 private BuildingDetail(int buildingId, string buildingName) 
     : base(buildingId, buildingName)
 {
     ...
 }
```

It will call the base constructor first. Also if you don't put the `:base(param1, param2)` after your constructor, the base's empty constructor will be called.

Comment: he'll also have to convert the base constructor to `protected`

Comment: It's okay, the constructor can be made protected.